# getting error while filling dataset using ADO.NET - Timeout expired

Tags: c#, gridview, ado.net, dataset, sqldataadapter

Geting error saying:

> "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." 
>   its getting 700 records but taking 45 sec . i think so its the issue. 
>   in this code how to add cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

My code is:

```
Dap_Proj = new SqlDataAdapter("select LinkId,LinkName,CategoryId, ReportLinks,SubmissionStatus,convert(nvarchar(18),LnkSubmsnDate) as LnkSubmsnDate, convert(nvarchar(18), LnkUpdateDate) as LnkUpdateDate,LnkSubmtdBy,K.KeyWord,RenewalDate  from tbl_Link L left join Tbl_keywords K on L.KeywordID=K.KeywordID  where 

(SubmissionStatus='Approved'or SubmissionStatus='Waiting for Approval') and  LnkSubmtdBy='" + Session["LoginUser"].ToString() + "' and Convert(Char(4),LnkSubmsnDate,100) in (select Convert(Char(4),LnkSubmsnDate,100) from tbl_Link )order by case when RenewalDate is null then 1 else 0 end,RenewalDate", connection);

            ds = new DataSet();
            Dap_Proj.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: problem seems to be with your database.Either your query is too complex or returning many number of rows.execute your query in sql server and check whether it executes

Comment: Try declaring your command and then setting its Timeout value to 0 `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("YourQuery");` `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;`

Comment: its executing and getting records but taking 44 sec.and retrieving 700 records@shreesha

Comment: commndtimeout = 0 means what. no timeout ?if i will give timeout = 60 , what will happen@Dumisani

Comment: Yes 0 means "don't timeout". If you give it 60 it will timeout after a minute.

Comment: ok got it..thanks@Dumisani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set command timeout on sqlDataAdapter try this

```
SqlDataAdapter Dap_Proj = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQLString, conUS);
Dap_Proj .SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=120;
```